# difficulties with dual monitor setup

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

So, I have an AMD APU with an integrated Radeon, VGA and HDMI outputs.
I'm currently using the HDMI output with a DVI adapter for my main monitor, and I'd like to add a second monitor using VGA.

For some reason though, when I plug in the second monitor, both screens go black until I reboot.

If I plug in my main monitor with both connections though, it works fine.  I can set it to "duplicate desktop" and everything with no problems, but then I unplug the main monitor from the VGA port, keep it plugged into the HDMI, and plug the second monitor back into the VGA and the screens both go black.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure that you are using the latest drivers for both the motherboard and the graphics. Does your motherboard have a DVI connection as well or just HDMI/VGA?

Comment: @kobaltz just VGA/HDMI unfortunately.  the drivers i have now were just installed a couple weeks ago.

Comment: When you say "I can plug both into main monitor" your main monitor has multiple input capability , and you can switch between both pictures (or pip)?  With main monitor and both connects ,When you boot you get bios screen on both inputs? . . Then "plug second monitor both screens go black until reboot" And at reboot with 2 monitors it works or Not? . . and On a reboot with both monitors connected, do you get bios screen on both?

Comment: i didn't check both inputs during boot, but i have a feeling only one would show the bios screen.  it's been that way with past computers for me iirc.  with both monitors at boot, it shows the boot screen on the VGA (second) monitor, then once the "starting windows" screen goes away, both screens are stuck as black.  if i boot with both inputs on one monitor it also works fine.

Comment: good extra info. I forgot one, if you connect only 2nd monitor? What I would do next probably would be to set the monitor I could see still, to low-res , if possible connect up other monitor alone set it low-res (via software). Then try to get a view (of any kind) going on the both, then adjust up from there.  I would also be setting the refresh low like 60.  Then I would also analise and mabey uninstall any monitor "driver" (profile) in the device manager.

Comment: if i only connect the 2nd, it does the same as with both.  shows the windows logo, then goes black before the login screen.